# Getting MySQL to properly distinguish Japanese characters in SELECT calls

Tags: mysql, unicode, utf-8

I'm setting up a database to do some linguistic analysis, and Japanese Kana are giving me just a bit of trouble.

Unlike other questions on this so far, I don't know that it's an encoding issue, per se.  I've set the coallation to `utf8_unicode_ci`, and on the surface it's saving and recalling most things all right.

The problem, however, is when I get into related kana, such as キ (ki) and ギ (gi).  For sorting purposes, Japanese doesn't distinguish between the two unless they are in direct conflict.  So for example:

- ぎ (gi) comes before きかい (kikai)
- きる (kiru) comes before ぎわく (giwaku)
- き (ki) comes before ぎ (gi)

It's this behavior that I think is at the root of my problem.  When loading my data set from an external file, I had it do a SELECT call to verify that specific readings in Japanese had not already been logged.  If it was already there, it would fetch the ID so it could be paired to a headword; otherwise a new entry was added and paired thereafter.

What I noticed after I put everything in is that wherever two such similar readings occurred, the first one encountered would be logged and would then show up as a false positive for the other if it showed up.  For example:

- キョウ (kyou) appeared first, so characters with ギョウ (gyou) got paired with kyou instead
- ズ (zu) appeared before ス (su), so likewise even more characters got incorrectly matched.

I can go through and manually sort it out if need be, but what I would really like to do is set the database up to take a stricter view regarding differentiating between characters (e.g. if the characters have two different UTF-8 code points, treat them as different characters).  Is there any way to get this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `utf8_bin` to get a collation that compares characters by their Unicode code points.

The `utf8_general_ci` collation also distinguishes キョウ and ギョウ.

Answer (score 1):

when saving to database
save it as binary 
and when calling back change it to Japanese
same problem accorded with me with Arabic language

Comment: I'm sorry but this does not answer the question